# New tag suggestion

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed that among the available tags there are `joomla-component` / `component` and `joomla-module` / `module`, but only `plugin`. Wouldn't it make sense to add `joomla-plugin` as well? Maybe not very important, but it would make sense to follow the same scheme.

Also, as this is a Joomla forum, shouldn't `joomla-component` and `component` etc. simply be tag synonyms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed I agree.

I see no point in using [joomla-component](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joomla-component) **and** [component](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/component). This is a Joomla specific StackExchange site, therefore I don't think people need to be reminded that the component, module or plugin are part of Joomla. Even synonyms I don't think would be necessary.

The likes of [joomla-component](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joomla-component) or [joomla-module](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joomla-module) should only really be used on non-specific Exchange sites, such as StackOverflow or Pro Webmasters

Comment: Yes, removing the `joomla-` prefix makes sense on Joomla StackExchange. How does the process of changing/removing tags work?

Comment: There is a soft delete feature that removes any tags at midnight (UTC) with no questions. So what could be done is, edit all questions that use the [tag:joomla-component] and change them to [tag:component]. I'm not sure if there are any other ways to deal with this to be honest

Comment: That sounds like a possible solution, as there are still quite few questions with these tags. I also noticed that both `modules` and `module` exists, are there any reasons to have both?

Comment: Tags are simply created when a user types a custom one in. I think a mass prune session might be an idea. Something I don't mind doing with a bit of help

Comment: I'll help, but my edits has to be approved...

Comment: approved them :)

Comment: @johanpw - Approved all your edits too. I'm also changing `modules` to `module` on questions that contain it

Comment: @johanpw - Ok that's all of them I believe. I've edited the rest of them now. There are currently 8 more of your edits in the review section which I have approved but just waiting to get another approval from another member :) Thanks for the help, much appreciated